# Prepend WAV Header in NAudio

Tags: naudio, naudio-framework

I am resampling MP4 (Audio) file into WAV using MediaFoundationReader and ResamplerDmoStream to WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1). After resampling I send the stream to speech API for transcription, but the API fails because the stream does not contain the WAV header.
If I save the stream to WAV file (using WaveFileWriter), read the file again and then send the stream to API then the API works because the stream contains the WAV header.
Is there a way to prepend the WAV header to the stream after ResamplerDmoStream resampling in order to prevent the time-costly I/O?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WaveFileWriter` to write to a `Stream`. So in this case, I'd write to a `MemoryStream`, and the `WaveFileWriter` must be disposed in order to properly finalize the WAV headers. But then you'll have an in-memory representation of a WAV file.

One caveat, is that you might end up disposing the `MemoryStream` when you dispose the `WaveFileWriter`, so I have a convenience class in NAudio called `IgnoreDisposeStream` which you can wrap the `MemoryStream` in to stop it getting disposed before you use it.

Comment: Thanks for your details explanation. Using ResamplerDmoStream provided inconsistent results on the API side so eventually I ended up using MediaFoundationResampler instead. I tried WaveFileWriter.Write but it requires to know the length of the byte array in order to create a stream of appropriate size and MediaFoundationResampler does not provide getter for Length. How can I create a stream from MediaFoundationResampler of appropriate size?