# Wrapping a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, naudio

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328396/prepend-wav-header-in-naudio#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328396/prepend-wav-header-in-naudio#_=_)
Mark Heath said:
"You can use WaveFileWriter to write to a Stream. So in this case, I'd write to a MemoryStream, and the WaveFileWritermust be disposed in order to properly finalize the WAV headers. But then you'll have an in-memory representation of a WAV file.

One caveat, is that you might end up disposing the MemoryStream when you dispose the WaveFileWriter, so I have a convenience class in NAudio called IgnoreDisposeStream which you can wrap the MemoryStream in to stop it getting disposed before you use it."

How do I wrap a memory stream in c#?

Comment: [See its source](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Utils/IgnoreDisposeStream.cs)?

Comment: By passing it to the constructor of IgnoreDisposeStream.

Comment: Have a look at the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Disposing a MemoryStream does very little in practice, it merely sets an internal flag that makes its Read/Write methods fail.  No problem, you can still call its GetBuffer() and ToArray() methods to get the buffer content.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll post the code here when I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void ConvertMemoryStreamToWavFile(ref MemoryStream ids, ref 
 MemoryStream ms)
    {
        ids.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);


        using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter(new IgnoreDisposeStream(ms), new WaveFormat(22000, 16, 1)))
        {

            ids.CopyTo(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

        }


    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it did anything at all, as I ended up adding another loop to make the speech synthesizer speak again, which seems to properly close the Wav stream header.